# How do I set the onPress in headerRight attribute to point to my function?

Tags: react-native

I have a functional component from which I want to navigate to the next screen. But I can't link the function to be called to the `onPress` attribute of the `headerRight` component in the `navigationOptions`.

Here is the code implement of what I am trying to achieve

```
 export default function MapScreen({navigation}) {

  const FunctionToOpenSecondActivity = () =>
  {
      navigation.navigate('Category');

  }
   ... // rest of code
 }

MapScreen.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Report Issue',
  headerRight:( <Button title="Next"
    type="clear"
    onPress={FunctionToOpenSecondActivity}
                />)
};
```

Unfortunately, when the button is pressed it does not navigate to the desired screen or does not work at all. I wish to have a fix for this, please.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating header you can create your custom component for header, and pass the `title` and `left` and `right` buttons `onPress` as a `props`,

exmple :

```
export default class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        const { redirectLeft, redirectRight, backgroundColor } = this.props;
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBar
                    backgroundColor={backgroundColor}
                    barStyle="dark-content"
                />
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={redirectLeft} style={styles.ButtonTouch}>
                    <Image style={styles.iconStyle} source={this.props.leftImage}>
                    </Image>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={[styles.text, { color: "white" }]}>{this.props.title}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={redirectRight} style={styles.ButtonTouch}>
                    <Image style={styles.iconStyle} source={this.props.rightImage} >
                    </Image>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View >
        );
    }
}
```

Style should be :

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({  
    container: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: your_color,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        height: 50
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 18,
        paddingVertical: 10,
    },
    iconStyle: {
        height: 22,
        width: 22,
        resizeMode: 'contain'
    },
    ButtonTouch: {
        width: 50,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        paddingVertical: 10,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
    }
});
```